# 【i2c】RaspberryPiに接続した9軸慣性センサのプログラムについてご教示ください！！

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, センサー

LSM9DS1 9軸慣性計測モジュールを使ってI2C接続で加速度・ジャイロ・磁気・温度センサ値の取得・表示を繰り返すプログラムを作りました。

生データを表示するとAが加速度センサ、Gがジャイロセンサ、Mが磁気センサ、XYZはそれぞれの軸、Tempは温度センサ(謎の値)を出力しました。

このセンサの生データの値を加速度（ｍ/S^2)、ジャイロ(dps)、磁気（gauss）、温度（℃）に変換するプログラムについてご教示ください。

[image: センサの生データの値]
＜実際のプログラム＞

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import smbus
import time

addressG = 0x6a
addressA = 0x6a
addressM = 0x1c
getG=0x18
getA=0x28
getM=0x28
getTemp = 0x15

CTRL_REG1_G  = 0x10
CTRL_REG4    = 0x1E
CTRL_REG5_XL = 0x1F
CTRL_REG3_M  = 0x22

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

bus.write_byte_data(addressG, CTRL_REG1_G, 0b00100000)   #gyro/accel odr and bw
bus.write_byte_data(addressG, CTRL_REG4, 0b00111000)     #enable gyro axis
bus.write_byte_data(addressA,CTRL_REG5_XL, 0b00111000)  #enable acceleromete
bus.write_byte_data(addressM, CTRL_REG3_M, 0b00000000)   #enable mag continuous
def alter(alterdata):
        return alterdata if alterdata < 32768 else alterdata - 65536

# ジャイロ・加速度・磁気・温度センサの生データを取得して繰り返し表示
while True:
        dataA = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addressA, getA,6)
        rawAX = dataA[0]  | dataA[1] << 8
        rawAY = dataA[2]  | dataA[3] << 8
        rawAZ = dataA[4]  | dataA[5] << 8
        AX = alter(rawAX)
        AY = alter(rawAY)
        AZ = alter(rawAZ)
        print "AX:"+"%d" % AX  + " ",
        print "AY:"+"%d" % AY  + " ",
        print "AZ:"+"%d" % AZ  + " "
        dataG = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addressG, getG,6)
        rawGX = dataG[0]  | dataG[1] << 8
        rawGY = dataG[2]  | dataG[3] << 8
        rawGZ = dataG[4]  | dataG[5] << 8
        GX = alter(rawGX)
        GY = alter(rawGY)
        GZ = alter(rawGZ)
        print "GX: "+"%d" % GX  + "",
        print "GY: "+"%d" % GY  + "",
        print "GZ: "+"%d" % GZ  + ""
        dataM = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addressM, getM,6)
        rawMX = dataM[0]  | dataM[1] << 8
        rawMY = dataM[2]  | dataM[3] << 8
        rawMZ = dataM[4]  | dataM[5] << 8
        MX = alter(rawMX)
        MY = alter(rawMY)
        MZ = alter(rawMZ)
        print "MX:"+"%d" % MX  + "",
        print "MY:"+"%d" % MY  + "",
        print "MZ:"+"%d" % MZ  + ""
        dataTemp = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addressG, getTemp,2)
        rawTemp = dataTemp[0] | dataTemp[1] <<8
        print "Temp:"+"%d" % rawTemp  + "  "
        print("---------------------------------------------")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

もう解決されているかもしれませんし、
直接の回答ではありませんが、
Arduino用のライブラリで、Rawデータを直読可能な値に変換してます。
ライブラリソース内をcalAccelとかcalcGyroとかで検索してみて下さい